# Change 2 512Gb SSDs NVMe in Raid0 (1Tb total) to one simple SSD of 2Tb, is it possible?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, raid

Sorry for my bad english I'm french, I will try to be as understandable as possible.

I wanted to add more space to my Alienware m15 R4 PC laptop, I knew it has 1 terabyte of storage and that there was 2 SSD slots so I thought that I could add another SSD but to my surprise there was already one SSD in each slot, both of 512Gb, they are installed as a Raid0 drive (if I understood how Raid systems work correctly).

*Edit 1 :* I checked directly by opening my laptop, it was marked "512Gb" on each SSDs. When checking the drive on Windows it shows "Raid0".

So what I want to do is to remove both SSD and use the new one that I bought of 2Tb.

Can I clone the raid0 data onto the new SSD using a USB Type C adapter, remove in the BIOS the Raid0 then remove both original SSDs and finally insert the new one with the original Raid0 data ?

Also, Intel Optane Memory is installed on the laptop, don't know if that means anything.

*Edit 1 :* Intel Optane Memory also shows that there are t2 SSDs of 512Gb each that operate as a Raid0 drive.

Thank you for your time and consideration to whoever will read this and answer !
Have a great day or night !

Comment: Are you positive about the current drives only being 512 GB, two 512 GB drives in RAID 1 would provide you only 512 GB of storage, not 1 TB? You should be editing your question instead of submitting commentary

Comment: I edited the question, thank you ! 

Comment: RAID 0 is stripped, which means your data is stored acrossed both drives. That fact will prevent you from cloning a single HDD to get your data.

Comment: There is a software called "Macrium Reflect", it can copy the data of an entire drive even Raid0 ones, meaning all its partitions even the boot one, not only from one of its SSD but from both. Could it work?

Comment: My first comment mistakenly mentioned RAID 1. Even in RAID 0, your total storage would be 512 GB instead of 1 TB.  So I am not sure where you are getting it.  My observation is that cloning only a single HDD will result in an incomplete copy of your RAID.  You would have to configure Windows so it's no longer in RAID mode before you disabled Intel RST the firmware.

Comment: Ramhound, Raid 0 does not sacrifice any space at all. If you have 2x 512GB drives then you get 1TB total space when they're in RAID 0.

Comment: (To Ramhound) But it shows me that I have 1Tb of storage (I'm actually using at least 900Gb and will need more space for my studies) and when I tried to see how much size where those 2 SSDs by opening and reading what was written on them, it was marked that they each have a capacity of 512Gb.
What I understood about Raid0 is that it is a "striped set" but if I have 2 Drives of 1Tb, I would still have access to 2Tb but the Read/Write operations will be faster.
Raid1 does divide by 2 the whole storage capacity because it basically mirror one drive onto another.
Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Alan, You will need to plug the 2tb drive into a USB port and leave the 2 RAID SSDs installed in the laptop to do a clone. If the RAID is set up in Windows then you will need software that can clone a disk while it is mounted and in-use. (Maybe Macrium Reflect?)
If the RAID is set up in hardware (BIOS) then you can use any bootable cloning software.

Comment: Ok no problem thank you very much, I wasn't sure if I could use a cloning software !
After cloning everything, will I need to deactivate something to tell the system that from now on I will only use one SSD and there won't be a raid setup? (In the Bios maybe?)

Comment: Ok I think I know what to do, I will have to change SATA mode to AHCI in BIOS settings, am I right?